# ANT if else tasks approach

Tags: java, ant, build

I had a query regarding ANT if else tasks. After browsing lot of stuff, i understood that we dont have direct if else tasks in ant.

My Requirement :

```
<if>
  <equals arg1="value" arg2="value" />
 <then>
      <property name="var1" value="class1"/>
 </then>
 <else>
      <property name="var1" value="class2"/>
 </else>
</if>
```

Below is my questions:

1) If we cant do it with ANT, can anyone suggest me the alternative approach to achieve it in ANT >1.6 versions
2) If i use antcontrib.jar in ANT_HOME/lib as an alternative, i have to keep the same jar in classpath in build.xml. can i have syntax for the same. I will cmd file which will call my build.xml file. Moreover, I have to set the property before executing any target in this case 2.

Comment: Isn't [Conditional Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Cristain, Thanks for your response. Conditional is also fine but i am lagging to create a code mentioned above using condition task. I am failing to set the property using condition task. Can i have code sample for my above requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pair of [condition](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) tasks with nested [conditions](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) to do a positive and negative match for your variable value, setting the property accordingly. (If the condition does not match, it does not set the property.)

build.xml

```
<project>
  <condition property="var1" value="class1">
    <equals arg1="value" arg2="${the_value}"/>
  </condition>
  <condition property="var1" value="class2">
    <not>
      <equals arg1="value" arg2="${the_value}"/>
    </not>
  </condition>
  <echo>the_value: ${the_value}</echo>
  <echo>var1: ${var1}</echo>
</project>
```

Output: condition positive match

```
$ ant
Buildfile: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build.xml
     [echo] the_value: ${the_value}
     [echo] var1: class2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Output: condition negative match

```
$ ant -Dthe_value=value
Buildfile: C:\Users\sudocode\tmp\ant\build.xml
     [echo] the_value: value
     [echo] var1: class1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Or more simply, define a single condition with a `value` and an `else` attribute for the same result:

```
<project>
  <condition property="var1" value="class1" else="class2">
    <equals arg1="value" arg2="${the_value}"/>
  </condition>
  <echo>the_value: ${the_value}</echo>
  <echo>var1: ${var1}</echo>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks sudocode for your response.